# ASP.Net not working with Https protocol

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

I develop ASP.Net Web Application and host on IIS with http protocol, everything working fine.

When I change from http to https, web page never finish loading and the browser was died (The problem only occurs in some page. If I logged with Normal User role, page would work. If I logged with Manager role, the problem would occur.).

Please help me to find the root cause of the problem.

I test on chrome, and capture the screen as below
[image]

Here is my web.config 
[image]

Comment: Didn't you forget to set up a certificate for HTTPS binding in IIS? I am not sure that this may be a cause though.

Comment: You may don't config for HTTPS

Comment: The problem only occurs in some page.